# UPDATE value from sorted JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users, which has a newly added field called `last_post_id`.

I need this to correspond to another table of posts so that for the latest post from that user, its id is stored in that new field.

I need to make an UPDATE sql query to handle the migrations for this new field. How could i do this?

**I have tried many attempts, for example:**

```
        UPDATE users u
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, created_at, post_id
            FROM posts
            WHERE user_id = u.id
            ORDER BY created_at DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) p
        ON u.id = p.user_id
        SET u.last_post_id = p.id
```

The problem: in the `WHERE`, I can't access `u`.

**Let me know if you have questions. REALLY appreciate the help.**

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? Does `(user_id, created_at)` is defined as unique?

Comment: @Akina Mysql version is: `5.7.31-1debian10`. What do you mean by are they defined as unique? Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: I mean does it is possible that there is 2 diffferent posts for a user with absolutely the same `created_at` value. And if such posts exists, what value must be used.

Comment: @Akina You can assume that this is NOT possible. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: what is u_id in post table, is it different from user_id?

Comment: @IndraPrakashTiwari Good catch! I meant to write `user_id`. Updated my question.

Comment: also, p.id means p.post_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `(user_id, created_at)` is defined as unique (or if we may assume that it is unique) then simply

```
UPDATE ( SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) created_at
         FROM posts
         GROUP BY user_id ) mp 
JOIN posts p USING (user_id, created_at)
JOIN users u USING (user_id)
SET u.last_post_id = p.id
```

This will work even when more than one post have the same maximal `created_at` value, but it is not defined what `posts.id` will be used in updating.